Blazor css isolation hot reload not working
I have a Blazor component named Comp.razor and nested inside it is a Comp.razor.css file. All of these files are located in a class library project. In my main project (the one I launch the app from), I referenced this component and everything works fine when the app launches.
However, I am facing an issue where I am unable to see any changes when I modify the CSS file and refresh the page. Strangely, if I modify the HTML file, the changes are reflected perfectly fine, but this is not the case with the isolated CSS file.
If anyone knows how to fix this issue, please let me know. Thank you.
PS:
I tried disabling browser cashing but it didn't work.
//
i tried to link CSS normally without CSS isolation and i ran into CSS file not found
i placed the CSS file of the component in wwwroot under the CSS directory and linked it in the component with 

I test in my blazor server app and I found hot reload didn't work for css isolation as well. Although the document here said vs 2022 + .net 6 should support  CSS hot reload. I'm afraid it is due to CSS isolation occurred at build time

have you had a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0 ?

@EmreBener i did but haven't found a workaround or a fix to my problem

as @TinyWang pointed out, CSS isolation occurs at build time, and the produced css files are bundled into one. This is not specific to Blazor, and the same issue exists on non-Blazor ASP.NET Core web apps. The bundling only happens once during the build and that's it. Naturally, hot reload will not work with css isolation, as there is no mechanism to re-trigger the process currently. This is a limitation of the framework.

I ran into a similar problem where using runtime razor compilation would break css isolation so I conditionally registered runtime compilation service like this:
#if DEBUG         mvcBuilder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();     #endif Meaning css isolation only worked on published builds, and I had to live without it during development just so I can have runtime razor compilation.

@EmreBener i understand , one more question , is there a workaround ? like another way to link CSS to components located in other projects in the same solution other than CSS isolation ? what do you suggest because i can't really build and style the site when every time i make changes to the app style i need to restart all over again
. because whenever i try to link the CSS in the traditional way i get a CSS not found error

CSS hot reload should already be working in Blazor. The problem is with "CSS isolation", which is something different. actually, CSS isolation is not necessarily something you'd need to have during development anyway.

@EmreBener okay , but i noticed whenever i try to link the CSS normally i get a CSS not found error

@EmreBener i am kinda new to blazor so yeah i need all the help i could get

which css are you trying to reference? you should edit those details into your question.

@EmreBener 1 m i'll edit the question to make it more clear

@EmreBener i edited the question but to make it quick for you , in the class library i put the CSS file in the wwwroot then linked the CSS to the component (component is also in the class library) normally with the link tag bu when the app launches i get CSS file not found

hot reload doesn't work for css isolation but it work for normal css. If you want to enjoy the benefit brought by hot reload, then you should create filename.css and put the file in wwwroot instead of component.razor.css.  then let's link the style file in the component. here's a related section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#consume-a-razor-component-from-an-rcl

@TinyWang i tried that but i get a CSS file not found , what do you suggest i should do ?

Hi, CSS not found always occurred when we use an incorrect route to the CSS file... maybe we could double confirm the routing. Otherwise, you might share how you link to the CSS file and where you put this file.

@TinyWang okay i'll sum the process ,
i have two projects in the same solution one is the main project which launches the app the other is a class library containing the component and in the wwwroot of the class library i put the CSS of the component there and i linked the CSS file in the component like this

when the app launches i get the component but with no style also a 404 resource not found
@LemonGrab I'm afraid you didn't link to the css file correctly, we need to link to this file  from the main app. For better showing, pls allow me to share what I test as an answer.

I created a blazor web app and an RCL, then in the RCL, I created a myStyle.css file and put it in wwwroot folder. Then in my RCL component, I used this class.

Following the official document to reference the component defined in RCL, and let's link to the myStyle.css file in the blazor app as well.

Link to the library's stylesheet in the app's  markup (location
of  content).


Just like you see, I modified <head> tag within my App.razor file, then it worked for me.


I had a test in my side just now with a new blazor server .net 7 application, and I found css isolation hot reload worked now. I'm using VS Version 17.8.3
